# What is wrong with this simple approach to a restful(ish) drupal 6 user authorization?

Tags: web-services, rest, drupal-6, authorization

This works... but is it wrong? particularly is it inherently insecure?

What am I missing? Do I really need services module to let me do some simple restfulish (and secure) drupal<->phone ap communication?

The idea is these urls would be sent via a phone ap (edit: and would use POST and **not** GET)

```
/**
 * Simple restish switchboard reading
 * This is not proper rest, but provide a quick and dirty framework.
 */
function _rest_go() {
  // login https://example.com/rest/go?mode=login&name=(yourusername)&pass=(yourpasword)
  // logout https://example.com/rest/go?mode=logout
  // logout https://example.com/rest/go?mode=me
  switch ($_REQUEST['mode']) {
    case 'login':
      $params = array(
          'name'   => $_REQUEST['name'],
          'pass'   => $_REQUEST['pass'],
          );
      $user = user_authenticate($params);
      $result = $user;
      break;
    case 'logout':
      require_once(drupal_get_path('module', 'user') . '/user.pages.inc');
      user_logout();
      $result = 'logged out';
      break;
    case 'me':
      $result = rest::myCiviID();
      break;
  }
  drupal_json($result);
  exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

These urls will work if you will try in web browser but probably not via phone app if cookies information is not available.

In that case, login api should return the user session id on successful login to the app and in the logout request you need to pass this session id to logout that particular user.

Comment: Thank Sumoanand - That's helpful. I'm particularly interested in knowing if this leads to security vulnerabilities

Answer (score 0):

A little bit of paranoia never hurts. As long as you don't validate/sanitize your data you leave yourself exposed to a possible security issue. How severe that issue is depends on how you're using it the input received from the user. It can range from just some small vandalism/style break of your site to big headaches like compromising your database.

The rule of thumb is: **never trust user input**! Always validate it and sanitize it. PHP/Drupal offer a great number of ways of making sure the data your manipulating is safe.

I suggest you start doing some research on what PHP has to offer when it comes to validation/sanitation. As far as I understand you're trying to build a light-weight alternative to what you think might be a bulkier module. By using PHP you don't have to bootstrap Drupal to have access to some of it's functions that sanitize content (e.g. `check_plain`, `check_url` and so on).

So go ahead and so some reading: [Filter functions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.filter.php)

Comment: Thanks Max, but I'm already in a drupal context. So I'm after an analysis based on the processing done by drupal

Comment: Don't mention it. Long story short, do some validation/sanitation, but be careful for double encoding/escaping. Somewhere along the line, I've had this kind of issues with just using Drupal's functions. That's why I prefer to use PHP functions instead, so I know exactly what to expect.